# How to trigger GitHub Actions only on specific push option?

Tags: github-actions

For example, If I define an action in `.github/workflows` like this:

```yaml
name: Trigger on release option
on:
  push:
    option:
      - release
jobs:
```

when I run:

```bash
git push --push-option=release
```

GitHub will run this action.But running `git push --push-option=foo` won't trigger this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

What you showed in your YAML is not valid. The [`on: push` trigger doesn't support `option`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push).

This was [asked in GitHub's community forum](https://github.community/t/how-to-run-a-workflow-only-if-a-push-option-exists/172840) before, but without a real answer.

I have dumped the entire event payload from a workflow triggered by `push` with a commit pushed with push options, but nothing was there in the payload.

---

If you're trying to release the code on demand, try working on feature branches and trigger the release when you merge to main.